# Codepoint of the 'missing glyph'-box

Tags: unicode, fonts

When a textbox, browser or other program can't display a character, or the character is not valid unicode, a white-box character is drawn instead to represent the missing glyph.

I assume that this box-glyph is a Unicode character itself, thus I am looking for its codepoint so I can use it. Does anyone know which codepoint is used, or perhaps if my assumption is wrong and it is not necessarily a member of the font?

At first I thought it might be the [White Square (U+25A1)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm), but, after I compared this glyph with an example, I found white square was smaller. There is a larger variant of it (medium and large), but these do not appear in the font under consideration, so these can not be the ones I am seeing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any unicode character who's glyph is missing in all fonts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475157/is-there-any-unicode-character-whos-glyph-is-missing-in-all-fonts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "glyph not found" character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730544/is-there-a-glyph-not-found-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find my answer, here on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636426/2718186

Particularly, the part that talks about [.notdef glyph](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/recom.htm). It seems that fonts reserve a special glyph, that is not mapped to by any Unicode point, to indicate that a character has no glyph in the current font.